# JSON Object to C++ model

Tags: c++, json, c++11, tree

I want to "convert" a JSON Object to C++ model. Let's say I have this simple JSON:

```
nodes:[
  {text: "Node1"},
  {text: "Node2",
    nodes:[
      {text: "Node 2-1"}
    ]
  }
]
```

In C++ I have this structure:

```
struct nodes {
  std::string text;
  nodes() = default;
  nodes(const std::string &text) : text(text) {}  
};
```

I also have a second "main" structure with a lot of other elements and it's like this:

```
struct Tree {
  std::vector<nodes> ftree;
}
```

In main I give the data:

```
Tree model;
model.ftree.push_back(nodes("Node 1"));
model.ftree.push_back(nodes("Node 2"));
model.ftree.push_back(nodes("Node 2-1"));
```

It's working but it takes all the nodes in the first level. How can I give data to a node inside?

Comment: First you need a recursive tree structure.

Comment: Just use a json parsing library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that structure to work you need another `nodes` inside the `nodes` struct. To differentiate between members (object) and types lets use an initial capitol letter for the types.

```
// Looking at this class
// You don't have a member to hold any sub nodes.
struct Node {                       // Note changed the type name to Node
    std::string        text;

    Node() = default;
    Node(const std::string &text) : text(text) {}  
};
```

To fix this add a member `nodes` to to the class.

```
struct Node {
    std::string        text;
    std::vector<Node>  nodes;   // Added this line

    Node() = default;
    Node(const std::string &text) : text(text) {}  
};
```

I would also note that your `Tree` structure does not use the same convention as your Json data.

```
// Notice the name here is `ftree`. But in the top level of your Json it is `nodes`;

struct Tree {

std::vector<Node> ftree; }
```

To be consistent with the Json I would change this like this:

```
struct Tree {
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
}
```

Now your main can look like this:

```
Tree model;
model.nodes.push_back(Node("Node 1"));
model.nodes.push_back(Node("Node 2"));
// Get the last node with back().
// Then you can get the `nodes` member and `push_back()` into that.
model.nodes.back().nodes.push_back(Node("Node 2-1"));
```

Personally I would use a method were you can read and write Json directly.

I use [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer). Disclaimer note: I wrote it.

```
#include "ThorSerializer/Traits.h"
#include "ThorSerializer/SerUtil.h"
#include "ThorSerializer/JsonThor.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    std::string        text;
    std::vector<Node>  nodes;   // Added this line

    Node() = default;
    Node(const std::string &text) : text(text) {}  
};
struct Tree {

    std::vector<Node>  nodes;
}
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Node, text, nodes);
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Tree, nodes);

int main()
{
    std::string  data = 
       R"(nodes:[
           {"text": "Node1"},
           {"text": "Node2", nodes:[{"text": "Node 2-1"}]}
       ])";

    std::stringstream jsonStream(data);


    Tree   model;

    jsonStream >> ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImport(model);
    std::cout  << ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExport(model);
}
```